# Fetch only N rows at a time (MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization, large-data-volumes

I'm looking for a way to fetch all data from a huge table in smaller chunks.

Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer a question from the title
use LIMIT operator

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,20
```

as for one from body, it's too **broad** to ask for a **certain**  code example, doesn't it?