# Stop Fetching data from a database after some point

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch data from a database until a certain condition is satisfied. If this condition is satisfied I want to stop fetching after that point.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
$a1=$row['Count']
if($a1<100){
$w1=$a1
//Now I want to stop fetching data after this point and take the variable "$w1" out
}
```

Comment: simply use exit; after your condition is satisfied

Comment: Use `break;` to exit a loop.

Comment: @PavanK `exit` will stop everything, `break` is better

Comment: Yup i agree, use break;

Comment: try [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599548/fetch-only-n-rows-at-a-time-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599548/fetch-only-n-rows-at-a-time-mysql)  or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573646/mysql-select-from-n-last-rows) may it will help you

Comment: try [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599548/fetch-only-n-rows-at-a-time-mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599548/fetch-only-n-rows-at-a-time-mysql)  or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573646/mysql-select-from-n-last-rows) may it will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `break`:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $a1 = $row['Count'];

    if ($a1 < 100) {
        $w1 = $a1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or `return` it out of a function.

Answer (score 3):

Best option is to give `limits` and `where` condition in your query

So that the query execution will be fast (You need to fetch less data).

Instead of fetching whole the data first and filtering it, Filter the data first and fetch it.

In your case : if you want to fetch first 100 records :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,100";
```

And if you have any condition then,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = '".$var."' LIMIT 0,100";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use break; or better you can use limit & where condition in your query

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
  $a1=$row['Count'];
  if($a1<100)
  {
     $w1=$a1; break;         
  }
}
```